# How do you call a object method from within an addEventListener() call?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this, addeventlistener

I am adding an event listener to a button inside of an object method. I am attempting to add a call to another method function but when I use `this.reset()` the 'this' points to the listener//button rather than the object itself.

This code has been refactored into an object and was working fine before. In that case I didn't need to use 'this'.

```
const colorGame = {
    reset: function() {...},

    init: function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < modeSwitches.length; i++) {
            modeSwitches[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                modeSwitches[0].classList.remove('selected');
                modeSwitches[1].classList.remove('selected');

                // These two lines are why I can't use anonymous functions
                this.classList.add('selected'); 
                this.textContent === 'Easy' ? numSquares = 3 : numSquares = 6;
                this.reset();
            });
        }

        ...
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.reset(); // This call also fails with the same error
});
```

Error in Chrome browser console : `colorGame.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: this.reset is not a function`

My intent is to use `colorGame.reset()` and have that called when the buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your `colorGame` object implement the ***EventListener interface*** by giving it a `handleEvent` method. Then you can bind the object itself as the event handler, and its `handleEvent` method will be invoked when an event takes place.

The value of `this` in `handleEvent` will be the `colorGame` object.

```js
const colorGame = {
  handleEvent: function(event) {
    // handle events here
    switch (event.type) {
      case "click":
        this.reset();
        break;
        
      default:
        console.log("unhandled event type");
    }
  },

  reset: function() {
    console.log("reset was called");
  },

  // Bind the colorGame object instead of binding functions
  init: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < modeSwitches.length; i++) {
      modeSwitches[i].addEventListener("click", colorGame);
    }

    resetButton.addEventListener('click', colorGame);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the handleEvent method special in such a way as to allow the ```addEventListener()``` to bind to it rather than a function? I thought the second parameter for ```addEventListener()``` was a function.

Comment: Yes, you can pass any regular object instead of a function *if* the object has (or inherits) a method named `handleEvent`.

Comment: simply, this is a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change your event listeners to use anonymous functions like:
`modeSwitches[i].addEventListener("click", () => this.reset());`
`resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.reset());`

Comment: That is one way my code has been however since I am also using 'this' to refer to the event listener I'd lose those parts too. Editing original to show.

Comment: @twodox: Then you'd just use define an `event` parameter and use `event.currentTarget`, which references the element. You'd do the same on my answer too. Using `var that = this;` is almost unheard of in modern JS. It was an unfortunate practice that we've moved beyond. Not sure why it still gets suggested as a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply store `this` into another variable. I usually call it `that`.

```
const colorGame = {
reset: function() {...},

init: function() {

    let that = this;
    for (let i = 0; i < modeSwitches.length; i++) {
        modeSwitches[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            ...
            that.reset();
        });
    }
    ...
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        that.reset(); 
    });
```